# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string - only in Windows XAMPP (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

Synopsis:

After copying a fully working Laravel Web App (Laravel 5.8, PHP 7.2) from my Linux web server to a local Windows XAMPP installation (same PHP version), I'm always getting

> "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

inside the unmodified standard Laravel register controller/view.

The whole Laravel folder was copied unmodified, the PHP 7.2 inside XAMPP runs with standard configuration (fresh install).

Any idea what could cause that to happen under Windows only?

Full Laravel error message:

> "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\xampp-7.2\htdocs\mywebapp\resources\views\auth\register.blade.php)"

Comment: may be `XAMPP` has different interpreter of `php`

Comment: show your code plz where you have used htmlspecialchars()

Comment: As I mentioned it's the standard unmodified Laravel code.

https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth/blob/master/resources/views/auth/register.blade.php

https://github.com/guiwoda/laravel-framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php

Answer (score 0):

So maybe this is the first time, and there is no previous old value

You can supply a default value, or you can insert the data from the user's existing record perhaps
for example:

```
@if(in_array($education->translation_of,old('education',[])))
```

here, specified empty array as the fallback.

Comment: In that case I would have to modify the standard Laravel Blade templates, which is not a good idea. Also, in that case, the error would happen in the Linux version as well, which it does not.